# When changed UIApplicationMain to use my custom delegate, getting a black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I created application delegate subclass UIApplication. Then modified main.m to tell UIApplicationMain to use my custom delegate class ( ELCUIApplication) as the principal class: But now i'm getting a black screen when open the app.

```
 #import "ELCUIApplication.h"

 @implementation ELCUIApplication

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];

    // Fire up the timer upon first event
    if(!_idleTimer) {
        [self resetIdleTimer];
    }

    // Check to see if there was a touch event
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] > 0) {
        UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
        if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
            [self resetIdleTimer];         
        }
    }
}

- (void)resetIdleTimer  {
    if (_idleTimer) {
        [_idleTimer invalidate];
    }

    // Schedule a timer to fire in kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes * 60
    int timeout = kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes * 60;
    _idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeout
                                              target:self 
                                               selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) 
                                            userInfo:nil 
                                             repeats:NO] ;

 }

- (void)idleTimerExceeded {
    /* Post a notification so anyone who subscribes to it can be notified when
     * the application times out */ 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) dealloc {
    //  [_idleTimer release];
    //  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ELCUIApplication.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
       return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,     NSStringFromClass([ELCUIApplication class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your complete source code for ELCUIApplication?  What class does it subclass?  Where are all of the other required `UIApplicationDelegate` methods? e.g. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` for example

Answer (score 0):

The black screen sounds like you are missing the important bit about setting your first (root) view controller and getting it on screen.  You need something like (for iPhone):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    self.myNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVC];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.myNav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

My advice would be to start with the template code that Xcode gives you when creating a new app.  You can then see which bits you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Black screen because your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not calling where you set app window and first `ViewController`. in main, last parameter is your `delegate` not custom class. So you use default `AppDelegate` or provide your custom.

Check last two parameter

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
       return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"Your custom class name", NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```